# Apply styles to submit button on input type text focus

Tags: css, css-selectors

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't find why. [Here's the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mMJZ8/)

Why does this work:

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus {
    background: blue;
}
```

But this doesn't?

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus #searchClubsForm input[type=submit] {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a comma

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo

Comment: Are you looking to change the background color of the submit button when focus has been applied to the text input?

Comment: No that's not what i want. I don't want the `background: blue` to be applied to `#searchClubsForm input[type=submit]` on focus over the text field.

Comment: Ah, I see. IMO the best way to do this would be to use Javascript/Jquery. There may be a CSS method, I'll try working on something and post below if it works.

Comment: Anyone can point out why this is a bad question? I'm not asking for something weird. Check here if you're not familiar what i'm doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent

Comment: I can't quite get the question mate. I already don't see a `background: blue` for the submit button.

Comment: @Harry On focus on `#searchClubsForm input[type=text]` i want background: blue to be applied to `#searchClubsForm input[type=submit]`

Comment: I think that's more because they have no clue what i was doing. "style is not applied to element after focus over textfield" I don't know how to explain it otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so you'll want to change this:

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus #searchClubsForm input[type=submit] {
    background: blue;
}
```

To this:

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus + input[type=submit] {
    background: blue;
}
```

This uses the adjacent sibling selector to style the button at the time of focus.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/mMJZ8/2/

Comment: yep that was the thing i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can style a child element on `focus` or `hover` of a parent element, but `input[type=submit]` is not a child element of `input[type=text]` and hence the current sample is not possible.

You should instead try using the adjacent sibling selector like below:

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus + input[type=submit] {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: It's possible using the adjacent sibling selector

Comment: ah, I was updating it mate. I meant the one shown in question is not possible :)

Comment: I'm just too quick for you! lol

Comment: I appreciate it, I leveled you out too, seems there was a lot of down-voting in this question for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma between the two selectors. The way you are currently targeting it would mean that you have an input inside an input, which isn't possible.

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus, #searchClubsForm input[type=submit] {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Why would i want to put a comma there? Dryden just showed that what i want is just perfectly normal

Answer (score 0):

Missing a comma:

```css
#searchClubsForm input[type=text]:focus, #searchClubsForm input[type=submit] {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: No why? I don't want a comma there

Answer (score -4):

You need to do this with Jquery:

```
$('#searchClubsForm input[type=text]').focus(function () {
    $('#searchClubsForm input[type=submit]').css({
        'background': 'blue'
    });
});
$('#searchClubsForm input[type=text]').blur(function () {
    $('#searchClubsForm input[type=submit]').css({
        'background': '#F0F0EE'
    });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/mMJZ8/3/

Make sure you have a js file though

Comment: -1 jQuery is not a solution. This can be accomplished cross-browser with CSS 2.1.