# On img hover show hidden ul

Tags: css

I have a div that holds an image and an unordered list.

```
<div id="holder">
  <img src="#" alt="some image"></img>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

I want the unordered list to be hidden until the div is hovered over.  The css I currently have is:

```
#holder {width: 100%;}

#holder > img {width: 100px; height: 100px;}

#holder > ul {display: none;}

#holder > ul:hover {display: block;}
```

I'm pretty sure this could be solved with javascript, but I'm just barely learning it.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Your `<div>` is not closed. Anyway, does what you have not work, and if not, in what way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style child element when hover on parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent)

Comment: The javascript example works great, except I can't move away from the image icon to hover over the list items (eventually they'll be links).  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#holder ul").hide();
 $("img").hover(function(){
   $("#holder ul").show();
   },function(){
   $("#holder ul").hide();
   });
});
</script>
    <div id="holder">
      <img src="#" alt="some image">
      <ul>
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
        <li>List Item 3</li>
      </ul></div>
```

What you are searching is here. It's easy with JQuery..

Comment: The javascript example works great, except I can't move away from the image icon to hover over the list items (eventually they'll be links).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Simple `$("img").hover(function(){` to `$("#holder").hover(function(){` Got it?

Comment: @strasbal That's alright! We are here to help and get helped ;)

Comment: @strasbal This achieves exactly the same effect as other answers using just CSS to add a hover effect to the `div`, just so you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `CSS` as below:

```
#holder:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nkzn43gb/)**

> NOTE - `<img>` will not have `</img>` From this **[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854998/2065039)** it is invalid and it should be closed like `<img src="#" alt="some image"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `:hover` attribute to the element you want to activate the change then add the child element (in this case `ul`) to the selector as follows:

```
#parent:hover child {
    /* css here */
}
```

Here is an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxkrmbh9/2/) using your code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added more code.  I only want the hover to work when it's hovering over the img not the parent.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @strasbal I updated my code to do what I think you want with just CSS.  However, if you want the bullets to stay visible to click on them, you'd be better off with the hover enabled over the entire `div`, not just the image.  I added links in my code to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#holder ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#holder").mouseover(function(){
    $("#holder ul").show();
});

 $("#holder").mouseout(function(){
    $("#holder ul").hide();
});
```

Comment: This was perfect.  The only issue is that when try to scroll over the list items, the list disappears.  Any idea on how to fix this?