# How to change color of a font-awesome icon inside a card on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have a page with a lot of bootstrap cards. When I hover on the card, I want the icon color to be white rather than black. I tried different methods but I couldn't succeed. I added a class like .fa-calendar:hover, I tried with fa:hover but couldn't succeed

These is my codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGOgMq

```
<section>
<div class="container">


        <div class="row mbr-justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-volume-up fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Stay <span>Successful</span></h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-calendar fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Create
                            <span>An Effective Team</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-globe fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Launch
                            <span>A Unique Project</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                  <a href="#"></a>
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-trophy fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Achieve <span>Your Targets</span></h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




        </div>

</div>

</section>
```

Comment: like this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZQvXe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the color you set for `.mbr-iconfont`

```
.mbr-iconfont {
  font-size: 4.5rem !important;
  color: #313131;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

when you hover over each box, the main parent element which gets :hover is the `.wrap` class. you can't change color of `.mbr-iconfont:hover` because the user may hover on other parts of the box (eg. the text or title or margins...). So, you have to set your hover style for parent element `.wrap` as in following:

```
.wrap:hover .mbr-iconfont {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Here is the [updated Pen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REqQEM)

Comment: see also this question: [Style child element when hover on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent)

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific you can hover over the class name. You need hover property and after that add the class name.

```
.wrap:hover .fa{
 color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color of all the icon to be same on hover then you can use the class name

Example:

```
.wrap:hover .fa{
  color:red;
  }
```

Else you can use id and then change the color

```
.wrap:hover #vol{
  color:red;
  }
```