# SVG color change inside a button CSS

Tags: html, css, svg-filters

I am having a trouble changing the color of SVG along with the button. I want SVG color to change when I hover onto a button with SVG in it, now it works just when I hover over an SVG image inside that button. Here is what I got so far:

```css
.round {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    line-height:118px;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0);
    border:2px solid #0090ff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.round:hover {
    background-color: #00aaee;
    border:2px solid #0080b3;
}

.svg:hover {
    filter: brightness(1000%) saturate(0%) contrast(1000%);
}
```

```html
<a href="/category/aktualnosci/" class="round"><img class="svg" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/gazeta.svg" width="60" height="60"></a><br>
```

Comment: Did you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :
`.round:hover .svg {
    filter: brightness(1000%) saturate(0%) contrast(1000%);
}`