# Changing text color on hover

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add a text color change on my `a` tag. Inside of my `a` tag I have two separate span classes. One to keep the text black and the other to have the text gray. On hover, I would like both these span text color to turn blue.

At the moment, when hovering over my `a` tag only the first span text turns blue, but not the span tag the has css to have text gray.

How can I make it so on over of the `a` tag both span colors turn blue.

Here is an example of my code:

```css
.gray-text {
  color: gray;
}
.gray-text:hover {
  color: blue;
}



a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a><span>Click Here</span> <span class="gray-text"> (Sub-Title)</span></a>
</div>
```

I've attempted to work around with by applying a `:hover` to my class `gray-text` which gives me the look I am going for but only when hovering over the gray text.

My expected to outcome is on hover of `Click Here (Sub Title)` the entire text turns blue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style child element when hover on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is a more intuitive solution. when you hover on the a tag change the color of the spans

```css
.gray-text {
  color: gray;
}

a:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a><span>Click Here</span><span class="gray-text"> (Sub-Title)</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use the `!important` flag when it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because `.gray-text:hover` only matches a hover over the text itself, not the link. To make this work, you can match against `.gray-text` that is a descendent of `a:hover`. Try it like this:

```
.gray-text {
  color: gray;
}

/* Change color of link */
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue!important;
}

/* Change color of text */
a:hover .gray-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `!important` flag (as all the other answers do) should be avoided, since it can cause issues with specificity down the road.

From the [Mozilla Web Docs on Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Using `!important`, however, is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.

A better solution would be to just turn all of the text blue when the anchor is hovered. The `!important` is not needed:

```css
.gray-text {
  color: gray;
}
a:hover,
a:hover .gray-text {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a><span>Click Here</span> <span class="gray-text"> (Sub-Title)</span></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this. You can update the colour of the text inside the `span` tag when `a` tag is hovered.

```css
.gray-text {
  color: gray;
}
.gray-text:hover {
  color: blue;
}



a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue!important;
}
 
a:hover span {
    color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<a><span>Click Here</span> <span class="gray-text"> (Sub-Title)</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Anwser only containing code without explanation can be considered low-quality. An anwser should always contain enough explanation to understand what you actually did and why it is working. Otherwiese it is quite useless for others to reproduce.