# How to translate an element while avoiding flicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having a list with a total of 5 elements and on hover, on any individual element, I'm trying to translate that element 7% in the x-direction and -15% in the y-direction with a half-second transition. It's all working well till here.

Here is the code:

```css
.listContainer{
    background-color:rgba(0,151, 19, 0.1);
    width: 70vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    padding: 4vh;
}

.listItem{
    background-color:rgba(0,151, 19, 0.2);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 1fr;
    margin-top: 4vh;
    justify-content: row;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.listItem:hover{
    transform : translate(7%, -15%);
    background-color: white;
}

.itemRank{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(183 225 188);
    /* border: 2px solid blue; */

}

.listHeading{
    text-align: center;
}

.listImg{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="listContainer">
        <div class="listHeading"><h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1></div>
        <div id="listItem1" class="listItem">
            <div class="listImg"></div>
            <div class="listText"><h2>this is item 1</h2></div>
            <div class="itemRank"><h2>#1</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="listItem2" class="listItem">
            <div class="listImg"></div>
            <div class="listText"><h2>this is heading 2</h2></div>
            <div class="itemRank"><h2>#2</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="listItem3" class="listItem">
            <div class="listImg"></div>
            <div class="listText"><h2>this is heading 3</h2></div>
            <div class="itemRank"><h2>#3</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="listItem4" class="listItem">
            <div class="listImg"></div>
            <div class="listText"><h2>this is heading 4</h2></div>
            <div class="itemRank"><h2>#4</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="listItem5" class="listItem">
            <div class="listImg"></div>
            <div class="listText"><h2>this is heading 5</h2></div>
            <div class="itemRank"><h2>#5</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

But here the problem is, Let's say you hovered between that first 7% of the element in the x-direction as shown in the image, then the element translates 7% in the x direction and leaves the hovered area and that's why tries to come back to its original position but it again comes in the hovered area and that's why again translates and leaves the hovered area that's why again come back and that's how it goes in a continuous to and forth motion. So, what can I do to solve this...?

Comment: You can add a wrapper to this element then give this css to the wrapper. Since you hover and move the element it leaves mouse cursor.

Comment: But @gguney  how can I translate an element on hovering over some other element

Comment: you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent

Comment: Hey brother @gguney  , it worked perfectly..Thanks......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a div around your list items and use it to attach the hover class. This will avoid the flicker you see.

Take a look at the code below

```css
.listContainer{
    background-color:rgba(0,151, 19, 0.1);
    width: 70vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    padding: 4vh;
}

.listItem{
    background-color:rgba(0,151, 19, 0.2);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 1fr;
    margin-top: 4vh;
    justify-content: row;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

/** new change **/
.listItemWrapper:hover .listItem{
    transform : translate(7%, -15%);
    background-color: white;
}

.itemRank{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(183 225 188);
    /* border: 2px solid blue; */

}

.listHeading{
    text-align: center;
}

.listImg{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="listContainer">
<div class="listHeading">
    <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
</div>

<div class="listItemWrapper"> <!-- Notice this wrapper -->
    <div id="listItem1" class="listItem">
        <div class="listImg"></div>
        <div class="listText">
            <h2>this is item 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRank">
            <h2>#1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listItemWrapper">
    <div id="listItem2" class="listItem">
        <div class="listImg"></div>
        <div class="listText">
            <h2>this is heading 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRank">
            <h2>#2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listItemWrapper">
    <div id="listItem3" class="listItem">
        <div class="listImg"></div>
        <div class="listText">
            <h2>this is heading 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRank">
            <h2>#3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listItemWrapper">
    <div id="listItem4" class="listItem">
        <div class="listImg"></div>
        <div class="listText">
            <h2>this is heading 4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRank">
            <h2>#4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listItemWrapper">
    <div id="listItem5" class="listItem">
        <div class="listImg"></div>
        <div class="listText">
            <h2>this is heading 5</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRank">
            <h2>#5</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```