# How to change color of a tag when i hover over a div

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML structure like this

There's a div with an a tag inside of it. I want it that when I hover over the div, the background color of the div changes and the color of its a tag changes to black.

Is it possible to do it in CSS or do I have to use js?

```
<div class="example"><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
```

Nothing really worked out for me...

I tried these weird, a:hover + .div, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp check this it will help to understand

Comment: Better yet, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors. The anchor is a child, or descendant, of your div.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style child element when hover on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217244/style-child-element-when-hover-on-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your link. With the `a:link` you can change the links default color and with the `a:visited` you can make sure it keeps the color after you have visited the link.

With the `a:hover` `color:` you can change the color of the text itself when hovering and the `background-color` of course changes the color of just that. Let me know if you have any more questions.

```css
.example a:link, .example a:visited {
    color: green;
}
.example a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="example"><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "a:hover .example" instead of "a:hover + .div". The point is only added to reference a class name, if you just want to target a tag, you don't need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
.follow:hover {
    background-color: white;
  }

  .follow:hover>a {
    color: black;
    transition: 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
```

Thats the solution i found out for myself, idk if you guys understood what i meant, still thanks!

Comment: This is literally what I answered

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .example:hover a{
    color:black;
 }
 .example:hover {
     background:red;
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Do this;

```css
.example:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.example:hover > a {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"><a href="#">TEXT</a></div>
```